# Como criar FILA passando uma STRUCT

Tags: c, struct, fila

Estou tentando criar um código no qual irei inserir 10 nomes de candidatos em uma fila usando uma estrutura em C. Porém não tenho muito conhecimento em estrutura de dados em C.

Eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
#define TAM 5

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


    typedef struct
    {

        int final;
        int inicio;
        int tamanho;   
        int contador;

        char *vetorFila[TAM];

    }  pretendentes;


    void ListarNomesDosPretendentes();
    void removerNomesDosPretendentes();
    void receberNomesDosPretendentes();
    void armazenarNomesDosPretendentes();


    int main(void)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");        


        int menu = 0;
        int operacao = 0;


            do
            {
                printf("1 - Inserir nome\n");
                printf("2 - Remover nome\n");
                printf("3 - Exibir fila\n");
                scanf("%i", &menu);

            } while(menu < 0 && menu > 3);


            switch (operacao)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    receberNomesDosPretendentes();
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    removerNomesDosPretendentes();
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    ListarNomesDosPretendentes();
                }
            }

        return 0;
    }



    void receberNomesDosPretendentes()
    {
        static char nomes[10], *ptr;

        printf("Digite o nome ou aperte ENTER para sair.");
        do
        {
            printf("\n\nDigite o nome do pretendente: ");
            gets(nomes);

            ptr = (char*) malloc(strlen(nomes));
            strcpy(ptr, nomes);

            armazenarNomesDosPretendentes(ptr);

        } while(*nomes);
    }



    void armazenarNomesDosPretendentes(pretendentes *Pretendente, char *ptr)
    {
        if(Pretendente -> inicio == TAM)
        {
            printf("A fila está cheia.");
            return 0;
        }

        Pretendente -> vetorFila[Pretendente->inicio] = ptr;
        Pretendente -> inicio++;

    }

    void removerNomesDosPretendentes(pretendentes *Pretendente)
    {
        if(Pretendente -> inicio == Pretendente -> final)
        {
            printf("A fila está vazia.");
            return 0;
        }

        Pretendente -> final--;

    }

    void ListarNomesDosPretendentes(pretendentes *Pretendente)
    {
        int i;

        for(i = Pretendente -> final; i < TAM; i++)
        {
            printf("Pretendente %d: %s", i+1, Pretendente -> vetorFila[i]);
        }
    }
```

Mas logo quando rodo está dando um erro, alguém me ajuda a identificar o erro? Ele roda porém logo quebra...

Comment: "int pinicial" deve ser global, assim. Você sempre está inserido na posição 0. Você pode usar "static int pinicial"

Comment: Provavelmente o pior livro de C já escrito.

Comment: Curiosamente o seu código é igual ao [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/estrutura-de-dados-como-utilizar-struct-em-fila-em-c#comment594056_292095). E não resisto em fazer a mesma questão que fiz. A função `qstore` é suposto fazer o que ?

Comment: @Isac A função de qstore é armazenar em fila os nomes inseridos pelo usuário.

Comment: @Maniero Qual livro de linguagem C você me indicaria? Preciso de referências sólidas, recorri aos livros.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info

Comment: Tem tutorial sobre fila na internet, dei um google e [achei esse](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-set-1introduction-and-array-implementation/). Nem li, não sei se é bom, mas como é um assunto extremamente básico, qualquer tutorial deve servir